# PYTHON why won't my python IDLE recognise numpy as a module, despite numpy being used fine when pythob is ran in cmd?

Tags: python, numpy, module, package

```
import numpy as np

h = [1.87, 1.87, 1.82, 1.91, 1.90, 1.85]
w = [81.65, 97.52, 95.25, 92.98, 86.18, 88.45]

numpy_h = np.array(h)
numpy_w = np.array(w)

print(numpy_h)
```

simple code right? this runs fine in cmd, printing `[1.87 1.87 1.82 1.91 1.9 1.85]`
but when run in the python IDLE it errors out: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'`
i have checked my \python38-32\Lib\site-packages folder and indeed numpy is installed, to my knowledge correctly. How can a module be used in cmd but not in the IDLE?

Comment: do you use virtual environment ?

Comment: @AcaNg i use ConEmu as an emulator for the console, but apart from that no; I installed numpy using the pip in the windows console

Answer (score 0):

solved: reinstalled my python version and upgraded pip